# Laravel update/edit using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was trying to update my table but I couldn't make it work.. I always end up with the error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

**Here is my Controller:**

```
 public function show_score($id)
    {

        $scores = Score::with(['lead','subject'])->where(['subject_id'=>$id])->get();

        return view('markbook.show_score',compact('scores'));
    }

    public function update_score(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');

         $scores = Score::find($id);
         foreach ($scores as $datas) {
         $datas->jan_ap=$request->input('jan_ap');
         $datas->jan_hm=$request->input('jan_hm');
         $datas->save();  

        }


    }

route:
Route::get('markbook/scores/{id}', 'MarkbookController@show_score' );
Route::post('markbook/scores', 'MarkbookController@update_score');
```

Here is my table I'm trying to loop the updated score:

[image]

Comment: `Score::find($id);` finds _one_ item/row, what are you trying to loop over here?

Comment: im trying to loop Jan_ap and jan_hm update them

Comment: and where is $datas declared?

Comment: $scores = Score::find($id); returns 1 object right?

Comment: wwait and see my table i update my question

Comment: `Score::find($id);` always return you a single row.

Comment: you want to update `jan_ap` and `jan_hw` for all row  ?

Comment: yes is it possible?

Comment: yes, but is there any condition to fetch a group of students ? i mean update value for a list of students who join in `January` like this

Comment: i don't know also.. do i need to? can i just get the id row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174862/discussion-between-rkj-and-grace).

Comment: no need for that one not so particular already fetching data from subject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From chat discussion what found is that you want to update multiple scores, which is listed in tr, td. You can change it like this

**Change in view**

```
@foreach($scores as $score) 
    <tr> 
        <td>{{$score->lead->student_name}} <input type="hidden" name="scores[{{$loop->index}}][id]" value="{{$score->id}}"></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="scores[{{$loop->index}}][jan_ap]" value="{{$score->jan_ap}}"></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="scores[{{$loop->index}}][jan_hm]" value="{{$score->jan_hm}}"></td> 
    </tr> 
@endforeach
```

**Controller update score**

```
public function update_score(Request $request) 
{ 
    $scores = $request->input('scores');  //here scores is the input array param 

    foreach($scores as $row){
        $score = Score::find($row['id']); 
        $score->jan_ap = $row['jan_ap']; 
        $score->jan_hm = $row['jan_hm']; 
        $score->save(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Score::find($id)` you're only ever going to return 1 result so there won't be anything to foreach over.

If you just want to update a single row in the table you don't need to foreach it.

You can simply run

```
$score = Score::find($request->input($id));
$score->jan_ap = $request->input('jan_ap');
$score->jan_hm = $request->input('jan_hm');
$score->save();
```

if you want to return multiple rows you need to change your find to a `get()`

so `$scores = Score::where('something', $request->input('something))->get();`

If you want to update every row in the table with the same information you'd do a:

`$scores = Score::all();`

That would return every row in the table.

Comment: how bout multiple rows example two student

Comment: Then you need to chance your find to a get();

Comment: do i still need the for each loop?

Comment: Yes, if you're returning multiple rows.

Comment: side note: if you pass an array/Arrayable to `find` you will get a collection

Comment: Nice @lagbox I did not know this.