# How to make a post request to a protected Laravel API route with JavaScript using the API token?

Tags: javascript, laravel, authentication, post, protected

**Description**

I have a table, where i collect values from checkboxes with JavaScript. This values should be send to a protected API route in a Laravel backend.
I use the standard Laravel auth setup (out of the box).

**Question**

What do I have to send with the JavaScript post request for authentication and how do i do that? Can i add a auth token or something like that to the headers?
At the moment i get the reponse:

"This action is unauthorized".

`exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException"`

**Edit**

At the current point of my research the api token seems to be a simple solution for my case. But i can't figure out how to attach the api token to the JavaScript post request.

Thats the JavaScript function for collecting the values storing them in objects.

```
import SaveData from "../api/SaveData";

export default async function SaveMultipleReports() {
const table = document.getElementById("reports-dashboard");
const rows = table.querySelectorAll("div[class=report-tr]");

let reports = [];
for (const row of rows) {
    const checkbox_visible = row.querySelector("input[name=visible]")
        .checked;
    const checkbox_slider = document.querySelector(
        "input[name=show_in_slider]"
    ).checked;

    const report = {
        id: row.id,
        visible: checkbox_visible,
        show_in_slider: checkbox_slider
    };
    reports.push(report);
}

console.log(reports);
const response = await SaveData("/api/reports/update", reports);
console.log(response);
}
```

And that is the `SavaData` function:

```
export default async function SaveData(api, data) {
    const token = document
        .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
        .getAttribute("content");
    const url = window.location.origin + api;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token,
            Accept: "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });

    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
}
```

And thats the line in the `api.php`:

```
Route::middleware("can:administration")->post("reports/update", "ReportsController@UpdateAll");
```

The whole repo is [here](https://gitlab.com/leonp5/bueffelhilfe).

Thanks for your time in advance :)

**Edit 2**

For now i managed it without JavaScript. Put all the values, i want to update in form and load a hidden input for the ID of every object (the ID is needed for the controller afterwards).
Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299643/laravel-update-edit-using-foreach-loop/51299801).

```
{!! Form::open(["route" => ["admin.reports.multiupdate"], "method" => "PUT", "class" => "report-table"]) !!}

... // some HTML

@foreach ($reports as $report)
<div class="report-tr">
  <input type="hidden" name="reports[{{$loop->index}}][id]" value="{{$report->id}}">
  <div class="td-name">
    <p class="td-text">{{$report->name}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="td-flex">{{$report->body}}</div>
  <div class="tr-wrapper">
    <div class="checkbox-visible">
      <div class="checkbox-container">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="reports[{{$loop->index}}][visible]" value="1" checked>
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </div>
      <label class="table-label" for="visible">Sichtbar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-slider">
      <div class="checkbox-container">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="reports[{{$loop->index}}][show_in_slider]" value="1"
          {{($report->show_in_slider == 1 ? "checked" : "")}}>
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </div>
      <label class="table-label" for="show_in_slider">Im Slider</label>
    </div>
    <div class="td-buttons">

... 

@endforeach
<button class="floating-save">
  @svg("saveAll", "saveAll")
</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And a snippet from the Controller:

```
public function MultipleUpate(ReportUpdate $request)
  {
     $reports = $request->input("reports");

foreach ($reports as $row) {
  $report = Report::find($row["id"]);

  // giving the checkbox 0, if it isn't checked

  $isVisible = isset($row["visible"]) ? 1 : 0;
  $inSlider = isset($row["show_in_slider"]) ? 1 : 0;

  $report->visible = $isVisible;
  $report->show_in_slider = $inSlider;

  $report->new = false;

  if ($report->save()) {
    $saved = true;
  }
}

if ($saved == true) {
  $request->session()->flash("success",  "Änderungen gespeichert!");
} else {
  $request->session()->flash("error",  "Das hat nicht geklappt!");
}

return back();
```

The `ReportUdpate` function contains only that:

```
public function authorize()
  {
    return true;
  }

  public function rules()
  {
    return [
      "visible" => "nullable",
      "show_in_slider" => "nullable"
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about authentication but using an authorization middleware. There is a difference between the two.

Read about it here: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/authentication-vs-authorization-716fea914d55

With that being said, what you are looking for is an authentication middleware that protects your routes from unauthenticated users. Laravel provides a middleware called `Authenticate` out of the box for this specific purpose.

Change your route to be like so:

```
Route::middleware("auth")->post("reports/update", "ReportsController@UpdateAll");
```

Comment: Thanks for yur answer :) As far as i can see, the difference between authorization and authentication is clear to me. As you can see, i add the `(can:administration)` middleware. That restricts the access to the routes to the users who are admins. As i wrote, the problem is, how to attach the right token at the JS post request. Thats because i set up the standard Laravel auth setup and don't manage the authentication with a JS (React/Vue) frontend. At the moment i "solved" the problem as written in Edit2 above.

Comment: you can add your token to axios common headers if that helps.